# how to edit readonly file with vi

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vi

I'm following [this tutorial](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/05/setup-node-development-environment-amazon-ec2/) for deploying a node project on an EC2 instance.
I have to install npm and here what I have to do:

```
sudo su
vi /etc/sudoers
```

edit by pressing "i"

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

In order to save your changes, press ESC key and type “wq” and hit ENTER in VI editor.
But I can't because when I press "i" I got an error

```
W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: You don't need to use vi, it's just the text editor of choice for the person who wrote the tutorial. If you aren't familiar with it, I would recommend something simpler like pico/nano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think it was a bug from vi because I then try with nano and I had the right to write in the file.

For, node I try from the website but it wasn't working to, I think the problem come from amazon linux. I try with another instance with ubuntu server 14.04 and I had no problem

Answer (score 0):

The *second* problem is that with vi, you have to use `:w!` to actually overwrite a read-only file, when you are root.

The *first* problem is that whoever wrote the tutorial is giving bad advice: `/etc/sudoers` is *not supposed to be edited directly.*

You are supposed to use `visudo` to edit that file, to avoid shooting yourself in the foot.  Done the correct way, you should have no issues.